# Changing long variables to int type in large program

Tags: c++, fortran, migration, 64-bit

I am facing compatibility issues with integer types while migrating a large code base to x64 systems.

Fortran routines which expect INTEGER*4 are passed integers defined as long on the C/C++ side. Here is some sample code :

Fortran interface :

```
SUBROUTINE FOO(N)
    INTEGER*4 N
    !! DO SOME WORK
END
```

C/C++ code :

```
long n = 1;
FOO(&n);
```

Of course, this does not work when compiled for x64, and the integer needs to be defined as an int. Those types of calls are made countless times, and replacing them by hand will take forever.

Is there a more efficient way to make those changes ?

Comment: Write a script in awk or similar.  Also, if they need to be fixed size, they should be int32_t.

Comment: To late to help now but this is why we have, and should use fixed with types.  `int32_t` will always be 32 bits.  If your code need to work with specific sizes, the fixed with integers make that so much easier.

Comment: This has very little to do with migrating code to x86.  The above code likely never worked on any system where `sizeof(long) != sizeof(int)`.  The correct way to fix the code is to use the ISO C Binding feature of modern Fortran.  A less correct method would be use use sed and an appropriate regex pattern to convert the nonstandard `INTEGER*4` to the nonstandard `INTEGER*8`.

Comment: Especially considering the conventions are far from universal even in todays 64bit systems. See LP64 LLP64 ILP64 and so on. After you make this somehow work on Unix you may get a very unpleasant surprise on MS Windows if you continue to use `long` instead of what others are recommending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try a find-and-replace like Steve suggests in the comments, this should work:

```
sed -i 's/integer\*4/integer\*8/gI' *.f90
```

where `-i` gives replacement in the file, `I` at the end gives case-insensitive search, and the `*` symbols are escaped with `\*`. You might want to change `*.f90` to the extension you have or to `*.f*`.